# Displaying array value based on number JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using [star rating plugin](http://dobtco.github.io/starrr/) and in the star selection its return value in number that I am able to use it. Now I want to add another functionality on this that is, when I select star 1, it should show some message and the similar with star2, star 3 and so on.

The value of each star selection would in the array, but I am not able to print successfully, following

How do I show the message on each star selected?

```
$('rating').starrr({
    change: function(e, value) {
        console.log(value);

        //this is message
        var ratingMsgs = [
            'star 1 selected',
            'star 2 selected',
            'star 3 selected',
            'star 4 selected',
            'star 5 selected'
        ];
        var ratingMsg = $("p.message");
        //This is just showing the first value, but I want to value conditionally 
        ratingMsg.removeClass('hidden').append(ratingMsgs[0]);
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you get in `console.log(value);`

Comment: Change `ratingMsgs[0]` to `ratingMsgs[value]`

Comment: why are you doing .append(ratingMsg[0])  ratingMsg[index]  this index should point to user selection

Comment: number, like if I click 1 star then 1..if clicked 5 and 5 in number

Comment: @Dean Yes its binding correctly.

Comment: as AurA and Rory said.. you only bind-ed first value instead of the `value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ratingMsgs[0]`, give `ratingMsgs[value - 1]` and `text` instead of `append`

```
ratingMsg.removeClass('hidden').text(ratingMsgs[ value - 1 ]);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have updated based on your suggestion but what I am getting it, if I am click on star, message of star 1 should show, but its starting from star 2.

Comment: Try with `value - 1`

Comment: Excellent, worked as expected. thanks alot! +1 for the instant reply.